# Can not install wine32 on newely updated Debian 11

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

Recently I updated my device from Debian 10 to Debian 11.

After that, I tried to install wine on my machine, but the Terminal raised this error to me:

```
user@machine:~$ sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec58 : Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libavformat58 : Depends: libchromaprint1 (>= 1.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libglib2.0-0 : Depends: libpcre3 but it is not installable
                Recommends: shared-mime-info
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: adwaita-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: shared-mime-info
              Depends: libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcolord2 (>= 0.1.10) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0 (>= 1.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.41.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.41.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: librest-0.7-0 (>= 0.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgtk-3-common (>= 3.24.24-4) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libgtk-3-bin
              Recommends: librsvg2-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried to install all packages one by one, but the computer says that all of them are already installed.
Can anyone help?

Thank you.

---

Edit 1

```
user@machine:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

```
user@machine:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

```
user@machine:~$ apt policy librsvg2-2
librsvg2-2:
  Installed: 2.50.3+dfsg-1
  Candidate: 2.50.3+dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.50.3+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

```
user@machine:~$ sudo apt policy librsvg2-2:i386
librsvg2-2:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.50.3+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     2.50.3+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main i386 Packages
```

Edit 2

```
user@machine:~$ sudo apt install librsvg2-2:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec58 : Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libavformat58 : Depends: libchromaprint1 (>= 1.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libglib2.0-0 : Depends: libpcre3 but it is not installable
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: adwaita-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcolord2 (>= 0.1.10) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0 (>= 1.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.41.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.41.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: librest-0.7-0 (>= 0.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgtk-3-common (>= 3.24.24-4) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libgtk-3-bin
              Recommends: librsvg2-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: @StephenKitt sure, I just updated on 'Edit 1' section

Comment: Have you run `apt update` since you added `i386`? (I imagine you have, since `wine32` only exists there.) What does `apt policy librsvg2-2:i386` show?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, I run apt update and says all packages are up to date. I added the output you requested at hte end of the explanation.

Comment: Thanks; what is the result of trying to install `librsvg2-2:i386` with `sudo apt install librsvg2-2:i386`?

Comment: @StephenKitt unfortunately, the result looks the same as in the initial log. I added it on the 'Edit 2'

Comment: It seems like the breakage is unrelated to `wine32` (or at least, not all related to it). What does `sudo apt install -f` do?

Comment: @StephenKitt Nothing at all. It sais that everything is up to date. `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
`